# .htaccess redirect subdomain to main site - no exceptions

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect all requests for subdomain.example.com to www.example.com

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Seems to cause a 500 internal server error as does

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^example.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

So my question is why are these failing and how do I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried enabling the `RewriteLog` and see what the engine is seeing?

Comment: No I hadn't how do you go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your first two lines, add:

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: This still causes an internal server error, did I understand you correctly? Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Keep the Options and RewriteEngine lines the way they are, then add the two lines that I provided, removing everything else.